# Can't copy obj/Debug/program.exe.manifest, wont compile on MacOS (Visual Studio). How do I generate the .exe and subsequent manifest file?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-mac

The problem can be replicated by pulling the OrchardCMS from Git at https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard and then attempting to build the Orchard.Web solution on Visual Studio 2019 within a MacOS environment.

However, I don't know if my problem is specifically with Orchard. The project builds perfectly on my work unit that runs Windows 10. Yet when the project is built at home on my iMac running MacOS, the build fails with the error:

`Could not copy the file "obj/Debug/Orchard.exe.manifest" because it was not found`

I'm guessing that the .exe is not being built because of my OS and as such the manifest is not being generated, though this is just a guess. Is there any way to force the project to build the .exe and its subsequent manifest for the debug directory so the build succeeds?

If so, how do I go about doing this in a Mac environment?

System specs:
MacOS Mojave. V10.14.6 .
Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I'm an expert on neither, so correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that Orchard is a .NET Framework project and VS for Mac is for .NET Core/Xamarin/Unity. Perhaps you want [OrchardCore](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore)?

Comment: @Stephen, turns out you're on the money. I've been thrown into .NET and have no idea what it's about so this is news to me. Any clue as to whether you can compile .NET framework based projects on MacOS? I'm sure there's a few resources out there. Will report back if I come up with a solution. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac supports compiling .NET Framework projects. It does not support compiling projects that are Windows specific, such as WPF projects, for example. If you remove or comment out `<GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>` in the Orchard.csproj the solution will compile. Orchard.Web not seem to run after that change though - cannot find the `System.Web.Caching` namespace for some reason.